# Need help with Pattern/Regular Experession

Tags: regular-expressions, pattern

I want to check matching between string to string pattern that contain specific character as any.

For example:
Assume string pattern is:   "TEST ***ING NUMBER *"

For input:

"TEST STRING NUMBER 1"  is match

"TEST 123ING NUMBER W"  is match

"TEST SWING NUMBER 1"  not match (not enough characters to replace the '*' characters in ***ING)

Assume it can be done by going over the strings characters and compare them, but can it be done with Pattern/regular experssion?

Comment: Respectfully, I don't think this is salesforce related at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match any character in a regular expression in Apex (or any other major language with Regex support), you want to use the dot `.`:

```
TEST ...ING NUMBER .
```

You could also make use of the interval quantifier if you would otherwise have a lot of dots in a row:

```
TEST .{3}ING NUMBER .
```